# How to create button with dynamic links (that automatically updates with the last blog post link in a category) in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, button, dynamic-links

As title says I am trying to have a button on my home page that automatically updates the link with the link of the last blog post in a certain category

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to code shortcode (in child theme functions.php for example or make a plugin), that will generate this button HTML output, fetch last post url and add it to button. Then you can use something like [last_post_button] anywhere where you need.